# string ( dd/mm/yyyy) to date sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**EDIT**: 
The solution is in the reference post's solution .I was careless to overlook DATETIME--> Varchar(10)

`Syntax for CONVERT:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )`
```

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion) post

> SQL Server (2005, 2000, 7.0) does not have any flexible, or even non-flexible, way of taking an arbitrarily structured datetime in string format and converting it to the datetime data type.

So I am looking for a solution that solves this particular String format only.

Let's say I have a table in sql server with field :`inputDate` in `datetime` format

The following code works without convert/cast

```
SELECT inputDate
FROM   some_table
WHERE  inputDate > '01/24/2013'
```

But it won't work for

```
SELECT inputDate
FROM   some_table
WHERE  inputDate > '24/01/2013'
```

Throwing an `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`

Then I tried

```
SELECT inputDate
FROM   some_table
WHERE  inputDate > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '24/01/2013', 103)
```

Throwing the same error

Is there a way to **convert string in dd/mm/yyyy to be recognize as datetime format** in SQL SERVER? Or the only way, and the proper way is doing santization elsewhere?

Comment: The problem is you need to decide on one format or the other. How do you expect SQL Server to know if `07/08/2012` is July 8th or August 7th?

Comment: @AaronBertrand By using the 3rd agrument in convert function, I suppose. JW. solved this question.

Comment: I was referring to the previous post, which you referenced, where they seemed to want SQL Server to know whether to use 101 or 103 automatically.

Comment: Where does the string come from, and how is it sent to the server? I ask because I have in mind a few option that neatly side-step this hole problem.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  From Excel,    my solution was to use Format(date,"mm/dd/yyyy") , then using ADODB.connection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

have you tried using `DATETIME` instead of `VARCHAR(10)`

```
WHERE inputDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '24/01/2013', 103)
```

Comment: P.S. The solution is in the reference post's solution .I was careless to overlook DATETIME--> Varchar(10)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the information in this post : [ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813238/tsql-datetime-iso-8601)

I succeed to do  the following :

```
select convert(datetime,convert(char(23),'20140125' ,127),103) as MyDate
```

to get this :
    2014-01-25 00:00:00.000

Answer (score -1):

Use [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date format YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00. It will be implicitly converted to datetime in any locale

Comment: Thanks, that means I have to reformat my sql date string to yyyy-mm-dd in pre-processing?

Comment: No, this is not true! Try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH; SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-31');`

Comment: Check this MSDN Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx. (search for ISO 8601)

Comment: *sigh* Did you try what I posted? Did you notice that in the article the ISO 8601 format *includes time* and the `T` separator? If you tried what I posted you'd understand why I don't agree that YYYY-MM-DD is safe in any locale, in spite of what you might have interpreted from the MSDN article.

Comment: Why not suggest `YYYYMMDD` instead of that much more complex string? YYYYMMDD is universally safe unlike YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score -2):

Try to increase the length of your VARCHAR(10) to VARCHAR(14) like:

```
select inputDate from Table 
where inputDate > convert(varchar(14), '24/01/2013', 103)
```